# Script terminates after write() (Python)

Tags: python

I have a bit of Python code that appears like this:

```
try:
    f = open("stuff.txt", "w")
    f.write("Hello 1.\n")
    f.write("How are you? 2.\n")
    f.write("Goodbye 3.\n"
    f.close()

except IOError:
    print "Error Message."

<A lot more Python code here ...>
```

However, what happens is that it writes to stuff.txt fine, but it stops immediately after the first write() call. So, stuff.txt will, if you open it, contain:

```
Hello 1.
```

Another strange thing is that all of my code following that first write() call (the  stuff never executes, as if the Python script just terminated right then and there with the first write().

How do I stop it from terminating like this?

Also, does it make sense to write to multiple lines in a text file this way? The desired output would be (in stuff.txt):

```
Hello 1.
How are you? 2.
Goodbye 3.
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: close the bracket after `f.write("Goodbye 3.\n"`

Comment: do you get `Error Message.` printed?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with this code except the missing closing-bracket `)` at the end of `f.write("Goodbye 3.\n"`

```
>>> def test():
...   try:
...     f = open("stuff.txt", "w")
...     f.write("Hello 1.\n")
...     f.write("How are you? 2.\n")
...     f.write("Goodbye 3.\n")
...     f.close()
...   except IOError:
...     print "Error Message."
...   print "Outside Try -- Catch. This works fine"
... 
>>> test()
Outside Try -- Catch. This works fine
```

Comment: That would throw a `syntax error` and not a run time error

Comment: @BhargavRao, That is what I am trying to point out. There is nothing wrong with this code. The error lies somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah, It is just a typing mistake while asking the question I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing paren so you get an error each time, you should use `with` to open your file:

```
with open("stuff.txt", "w") as f: # closes your file automatically
    f.write("Hello 1.\n")
    f.write("How are you? 2.\n")
    f.write("Goodbye 3.\n") # missing closing paren
```